# NodeJs amazon-cognito-identity-js signUp succeeding without returning a result

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have imported `node-fetch` `amazon-cognito-identitiy-js` from `npm` and am trying to deploy a custom sign up lambda function.

```
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

const poolData = {
  UserPoolId: "ap-southeast-1_******",
  ClientId: "***********"
}

module.exports.router = (event, context, callback) => {
  return createUser(event, context, callback);
};

function createUser(event, context, callback) {

  let postBody = JSON.parse(event.body);

  /*cognito test*/
  const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
  var attributeList = [];
  attributeList.push(new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute({Name:"email",Value:postBody.email}));

  var cognitoResult = null;

  userPool.signUp(postBody.email, 'ke$2kelmDj123', attributeList, null, function(err, result){
      if (err) {
        cognitoResult = err;
      } else {
        cognitoResult = result;
      }
  });

  const response = {
    statusCode: 201,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: "register account", special: postBody["name"], cognito: cognitoResult })
  };

  callback(null, response);
}
```

For some reason `cognitoResult` will only return null, even though the user is being created in my user pool in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

That is because this piece of code

```
userPool.signUp(postBody.email, 'ke$2kelmDj123', attributeList, null, function(err, result){
      if (err) {
        cognitoResult = err;
      } else {
        cognitoResult = result;
      }
  });
```

is asynchronous and you are not waiting for the result. You just return the response while this has not yet been resolved. It resolves eventually (which you can observe by the user being created) but you have already returned from the Lambda function by then.

You can solve it by embedding the response in the `else` block.

```
userPool.signUp(postBody.email, 'ke$2kelmDj123', attributeList, null, function(err, result){
      if (err) {
        cognitoResult = err;
        // place error response here
      } else {
        cognitoResult = result;

        const response = {
          statusCode: 201,
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ message: "register account", special: postBody["name"], cognito: cognitoResult })
        };

        callback(null, response);
      }
  });
```

Note that you should also create an error response.